# Street Combinatorics - 6 by 7 grid

Tags: combinatorics

You go to school in a building located six blocks east and seven blocks north
of your home. So, in walking to school each day you go thirteen blocks. All streets in a rectangular pattern are available to you for walking.
In how many different paths can you go from home to school, walking only thirteen
blocks?

I want to say that the answer can be found knowing that there are $6!$ ways east and $7!$ ways north. Then, the answer would be $6!+ 7!$ .

I feel like this is way too simple of a solution to be correct.

Comment: I like the attempt.  To see the flaw in the logic, suppose the school were located 6 blocks due east.  By your reasoning, there would be 6! ways east, instead of only one way.

Comment: Of the thirteen total blocks you must walk, you simply *choose* the six you'll walk east on (numbers 1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 12, for instance). That determines your route.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this:

You have to go north 7 times and go east 6 times. How can you slip in the 6 "east moves" into 7 "north moves"?

The answer is then $\binom{6+7}6=\binom{13}6=1716$

Comment: I think you messed up the combination notation...

Comment: @RushabhMehta I did. Thank you for point it out.

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume the only moves you are allowed are moving north and moving east. Denote a move north as `n` and a move east as `e`. Hence, we need to make 7 `n` moves and 6 `e` moves, and we seek to compute the number of arrangements of these moves.

This is equivalent to the problem

```
nnnnnnneeeeee
```

How many distinct rearrangements are there of the above letters. Through some combinatorics, we find the answer is $${13\choose6}=\frac{13!}{6!7!}=\color{red}{1716}$$

Comment: This would be a utilization of the multinomial theorem, correct?

Comment: @Ludwigthestud That's one way of thinking about it.